# Верстка сайта проблема с контейнером

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

я заметил , что на моем веб-сайте если посмотреть через консоль разработчика обнаруживается 2 элемента синий и оранжевы. Подскажите что значат эти цвета , и мне кажется что контейнер должен быть одним цветом синим. Я использую референсный сайт для как образец, и там контейнеры все в едином стиле. Фото прилагаются.  [image: Это единая таблица, но левая часть окрашена в синий а правая в оранжевый, это базовый вопрос , но я понимаю что тут что-то не так.]

[image: Если брать референсный сайт то там такая структура.]

В чем может быть моя ошибка и как это справить?

Comment: Звучит как троллинг. Оранжевый это марджин. У тебя справа показаны цвета отступов. Зелёный паддинг, на будущее...

Comment: У вас, вообще-то, section выделен.

Comment: Точно вы правы, оранжевый  margin большой , а синие я не знаю что , это но оно маленькое. Так же не должно быть?

Comment: Я еще посмотрел и узнал что мой header тоже входил в эту таблицу.  Я его отделил, но потом увидел что у моей таблицы 
.ftco-section {
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin-right: 600px;
}
Потом есть еще один класс div class contanier и его css  тоже смещен + почему-то цепляется header из основного css ..container {
    max-width: 940px
px
;
}

вообшем нужно чистить main css.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще спасибо всем кто откликнулся, я добился своего [image: Весь синий контейнер занимает все пространство как у нормальных сайтов. Что я сделал , дак это просто удалили все ненужные классы, теперь осталось мобильно меню.]